# Training YOLOv7-w6 model

Tags: python, yolov7

I'm trying to train the YOLOv7-w6 variation of YOLOv7.

[This is the link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_D7ELWlcAFCKl_9749zZe0RfqocW8_2V?usp=drive_link) to my Colab notebook.

I'm getting the following error message, and it cannot start training:

```
     Epoch   gpu_mem       box       obj       cls     total    labels  img_size
  0% 0/1827 [00:00<?, ?it/s]/content/yolov7/train.py:353: DeprecationWarning: non-integer arguments to randrange() have been deprecated since Python 3.10 and will be removed in a subsequent version
  sz = random.randrange(imgsz * 0.5, imgsz * 1.5 + gs) // gs * gs  # size
  0% 0/1827 [00:01<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/yolov7/train.py", line 616, in <module>
    train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer)
  File "/content/yolov7/train.py", line 363, in train
    loss, loss_items = compute_loss_ota(pred, targets.to(device), imgs)  # loss scaled by batch_size
  File "/content/yolov7/utils/loss.py", line 585, in __call__
    bs, as_, gjs, gis, targets, anchors = self.build_targets(p, targets, imgs)
  File "/content/yolov7/utils/loss.py", line 677, in build_targets
    b, a, gj, gi = indices[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot locate this error in your Colab file, have you solved the issue?
If you require Defect Detection, I would like to recommend an online demo for [Anamoly Detection](https://saiwa.ai/app/free/detection/anomaly-detection), which I found to be free and user-friendly. Additionally, it also had [Yolo-v7 Detection](https://saiwa.ai/app/detection/object-detection) which was also free and easy to use.